# Shell remove a comma in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to remove first/last comma of multiple commas which are in between semicolon.

clarification: I have a comma separated key:value records in a text file which i want them to load into a db. Out of these records I have certain values which are separated by a comma as shown below. So, before i trim off key's from each record i want to remove "," which is in between firstname and lastname.

Note: All the names are not of same format meaning with first name and second name, some records are with only name.

Current format:

SNO:01, ID:123, Name: firstname, lastname, fname: firstname , lastname, sex:male, age:42
SNO:02, ID:124, Name: name,  fname: firstname , lastname, sex:male, age:40
     SNO:03, ID:125, Name: firstname , lastname, fname: name, sex:male, age:37
SNO:04, ID:126, Name: name, fname: name, sex:male, age:35

Required format:

SNO:01, ID:123, Name: firstname+lastname, fname: firstname+lastname, sex:male, age:42
SNO:02, ID:124, Name: name,  fname: firstname+lastname, sex:male, age:40
SNO:03, ID:125, Name: firstname+lastname, fname: name, sex:male, age:37
SNO:04, ID:126, Name: name, fname: name, sex:male, age:35

I want firstname and lastname to be as just name. To achieve this i want to make sure there is only one comma in between two ":".

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `sed 's/,//' file`?

Comment: In your example, wouldn't it not remove both?  You said you want to remove the first and last comma, so if there are two it would remove both...?  clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this awk.

```
awk -F: -vOFS=: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /[^,]*,[^,]*,.*/)sub(",","+",$i)}1' infile
```

Field separator = : , Output field separator = :

For each field, look for 2 comma.

If find, substitute the first by +

1 for print the line.